# difference between Gradle and accurev

Tags: java, gradle, accurev

Can any one explain the difference between `Accurev` and `Gradle`.

I am trying to use it in eclipse mars version.
I have a project  got  from `AccuRev` how can I import it as a `gradle` or as `AccuRev`?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

AccuRev -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AccuRev_SCM

Gradle -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle

Answer (score 0):

AccuRev is not a build system or project format, it's a source control management system like cvs, subversion, git, tfs, mercurial etc.

Gradle is a build system and project format similar to maven, but with groovy scripting, so you essentially get the declarative style of maven plus the imperative style of ant.

You would keep/promote a gradle project to AccuRev, but you would need to create the gradle project first.

So first things first you need to figure out what kind of project you already have as that has not been determined.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, a little search on your favorite search engine could help you to understood :

- **AccuRev**: Versioning tool *(like git)*
- **Gradle**: Build tool *(like maven)*